# Spring Rest Controller with Byte Array file

Tags: spring, rest

I am trying to send a byte array of a file content from angular to the rest api. But I am getting Http 403 forbidden. I don't have any security enabled. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I tried couple of different MIME types. The below is the http post from angular js and the $scope.encoded_file has the file in byte array.

```
$http({
  method:'POST',
  url:'http://localhost:9200/docupload',
  data:{'content':$scope.encoded_file,'name':'test','type':'pdf'},
  headers:{'Content-Type':'application/octet-stream'}
  }).success(function(){}); 
 };
```

**DocUploadService**

```
  @RestController
  public class DocUploadService {

  @RequestMapping(value="/docupload",method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST},consumes="application/octet-stream")
  public String UploadDocuments(@RequestParam(value="content")byte[] content,@RequestParam(value="type") String type,@RequestParam(value="name") String name) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("****Inside DocUpload*****");}}
```

The request doesnt reach to the service of course and I dont know why I am getting 403. Any idea?

Request Headers:
[image]

Added @CrossOrigin in before the service method but still no luck

Did the below added the CrossOrigin to the controller method.

```
public class DocUploadService {
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9200")
@RequestMapping(value="/docupload",method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.OPTIONS,RequestMethod.PUT},consumes="application/octet-stream")
```

Also, added global CORS registry.

```
 @EnableWebMvc
 public class WebMVCconfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

 @Override
 public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    registry.addMapping("/docupload")
    .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:9200")
    .allowedMethods("POST", "GET","OPTION","PUT");
    super.addCorsMappings(registry);

}
```

Comment: That could be a CORS issue. Do you have any other controllers that actually work?

Comment: Try inspecting the request (with chrome firebug for example) to see if there is any CORS error

Comment: It should be CORS. But I dont know how to resolve. Please check the edited section of the post. I added request headers.

Comment: See my answer, i think that could help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a filter to avoid CORS:

```
   @Component
public class SimpleCORSFilter implements Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, PATCH");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Location");
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

Or you can also use @CrossOrigin annotation:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9200")
```

There is an example here:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: Hi, thanks for spending time on this. I tried everything based on the spring doc for CORS but still no luck and I dont know what the issue is. I use spring boot so I dont have web.xml. I will try the filter approach too.

Comment: I edited my answer, that is a filter definition for spring-boot.

Comment: Hi Alvaro. Thanks for helping me on this. Adding the filter also didnt work for me. I finally had to disable the CSRF to make it work. I know this is not the correct fix. I will work on it further and update this thread if I find something new. Thanks.